# ssh: ProxyCommand forward host lookup fails

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to do an ssh multihop from my local machine to a server called cluster, using a server called merlot in-between. As per http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html, this is how I've made my ~/.ssh/config :

```
Host merlot
  HostName merlot.stat.uconn.edu
  User vdeshpande
Host cluster
  HostName stats.phys.uconn.edu
  User vdeshpande
  ProxyCommand ssh -q merlot nc -q0 cluster 22
```

When I type `ssh cluster` into the terminal, I am prompted for the password of merlot. After I enter it, I get this error:

```
cluster: forward host lookup failed: Unknown host
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

How do I fix this? I've checked that nc is installed. Also, I can ssh into merlot and then ssh into cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the ProxyCommand wrong. There are two ways how to handle it:

Preffered way is using openssh native switch `-w`:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p proxy
```

The netcat version looks this way:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -q proxy nc %h %p
```

You can't use your aliases in the remote netcat command, because it doesn't know them. Great guide are substitutions `%h`, which is the `HostName` you specified above.

So for you case:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -q merlot nc -q0 %h 22
```